# Create a Glassfish 3 domain as part of ant build?

Tags: ant, glassfish-3

I have a JEE6 project based on Glassfish 3.1.1 that is moving beyond the "one developer prototype" stage to being developed by a team.

Each member of the team will have their own local glassfish server.  I don't want each of them to have to go through all the manual steps of setting up the JDBC connection pool, JMS services, jdbc security realm, etc via the admin console, as I did when first developing the prototype.  It is error prone, and plus if I want to change something I have to tell everyone what to do.  I want it to be done as part of the ant build, so that it is a one-clicker, and then if I have to change something I can just tell them to do a clean to blow away the domain and then run it again.  So there would be an ant task to "config-glassfish" that would somehow configure the domain for them.

Despite extensive searching, I can't seem to find any step-by-step guide of how best to accomplish this.  Anyone have a link?

Would it be best to attempt to capture the fully configured domain and store that in our src repository?

Or should I instead have ant issue "asadmin" commands to create and configure the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just putting the domain.xml into the src repository, making an ant task to copy it over to the glassfish directory, and instructing other developers that when running that ant task, they should make sure glassfish is not running.

This worked for my case...

Answer (score 1):

You can do all of this with the sun-appserv-admin ant task. You can find more information here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/820-4336/beaev/index.html

Answer (score 0):

We struggle with this kind of thing at my work too, but only with a few developers.  One thing I really like is that Glassfish has the concept of a resources.xml which will cover a lot of the config.  I use this to pass around connection pool configs and JMS queues and it works really well, but it might not cover all your config needs.  The contents of the file are pretty much snippets from the domain.xml, and I haven't figured out everything it can do yet.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/ggoeh/index.html  http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2011/02/sample-glassfish-resourcesxml.html

I haven't tried other ideas since the resources.xml solves my major pain points, but you could take your domain.xml and work through any issues brought up by copying it to another developer's domain, then do variable replacement on the part of the file that need it.  That way you could have ant create the domain, then overwrite the domain.xml with the newly filled out one.

Maybe there is a way you could use asadmin backup-domain

One other idea would be Chef.  http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home